# .NET app only working in debug folder

Tags: c#, .net

If I copy all the files from the debug (or release) folder and paste it somewhere it stops working before open and process disappears without any message. Anyway everything seems to be fine in debug or release folder. Any Ideas?

As I'm trying to execute assembled files, I'm not able to debug it.

Comment: Are you using any dependencies? Any third party libraries that depend on native (C/COM/C++) components?

Comment: Are you copying over all ove the related assemblies.. are you getting any error messages.. perhaps your deployment techniques are flawed i.e you are doing things the way we use to deploy legacy applications / unmanaged code / executables Try launching it from the release folder outside of the debugger and see what happens..

Comment: Sure, but all dependant assemblies are in the folder.

Comment: Why not just debug it "How to: Debug an Executable Not Part of a Visual Studio Solution"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx

Comment: Make the first line of your project System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be any number of issues from missing assemblies, permissions etc, you can debug an executable from within Visual Studio if its running or not, the following links show you how to attach a process, or EXE, to the Visual Studio debugger.

[How to: Debug an Executable Not Part of a Visual Studio Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx)
[Attaching to Running Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to catch the exception to solve it. It can be due to almost anything ranging from references not found to IO-permissions etc.

For an easy way of just knowing fast, wrap your Main() in a try-catch and show a messagebox with the error.

```
 [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

A recommended solution would be to implement some kind of robust logging as [log4net](http://nuget.org/packages/log4net) or such before going into production.